# simple way of writing a binary code?

Tags: java

Need a way to write this in java without parse conversions. (Turns a number into binary)
Whats a simple way of writing this? "public static String toBinary(String num)"

Given a decimal integer D:

1) Divide D by 2, separating the remainder (remember, these are integers)

2) Always inserting to the LEFT of any previous binary digits in the answer, if there is no remainder, insert a 0, otherwise insert a 1.

3) repeat steps 1 & 2 until D is 0

Example:

If D = 49:

49/2 = 24 remainder 1, so insert a 1 into the answer: 1

24/2 = 12 remainder 0, so insert a 0 into the answer: 01

12/2 = 6 remainder 0, so insert a 0 into the answer: 001

6/2 = 3 remainder 0, so insert a 0 into the answer: 0001

3/2 = 1 remainder 1, so insert a 1 into the answer: 10001

1/2 = 0 remainder 1, so insert a 1 into the answer: 110001

D = 0, so the answer is 110001

Comment: We aren't going to do your (homework?) for you. If you make an earnest attempt but then get stuck, we'll be glad to help.

Comment: do my homework kind of question. not for stack overflow

Comment: why is your integer argument passed in as a String?

Comment: Literally been doing this for hours. Have rest of code written and everything works but I need to check for the user entering "q" to exit in a specific method. The only return in this method is a string. tried with the parse, works for numbers, but once i enter the q it crashes. Anyway I can upload code to here to have a peek. I have tried a bunch of different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you listed pretty much code themselves.

```
    public static String toBinary(int number) {
        int remainder;
        String numString = "";

        while (number != 0) {

            //% operator is the modulo sign
            //this returns the remainder of (number / 2)
            remainder = number % 2;

            //divides in java always round down
            //so don't worry about the last number not being 0
            number = number / 2;

            //add the remainder to the leftmost side of the string.
            //notice how this means the Integer.toString comes first
            numString = Integer.toString(remainder) + numString;


            //if you can't use the Integer class 
            //use ("" + some_int) to let Java automatically convert
            //an integer some_int to a String for you e.g.:

            //numString = "" + remainder + numString;
        }

        return numString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have the Integer already, you can simply do:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(49)
```

Which will convert the Integer to a binary String.

Comment: I was just about to mention this as well, you beat me to it.

Comment: From OP: "Need a way to write this in java without parse conversions."